# Номер строки в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Я выбираю значение в `ComboBox` в колонке таблицы, который:

```
private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string value = Convert.ToString((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem); // значение выбранного элемента 
}
```

А как мне узнать номер строки, в которой я выбрал, т.е. затронул ее, можно сказать!

За хороший ответ не пожалею своих очков уважения! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.hittest.aspx)
DataGrid.HitTest - метод
Получает сведения об элементе управления System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid в указанной точке экрана.
**HitTest(Point)**  Получает сведения о сетке, такие как номера строки и столбца выбранной на сетке точки, с помощью конкретного объекта Point.
**HitTest(Int32, Int32)**   Получает такие сведения, как номера строки и столбца выбранной на сетке точки, используя координаты x и y, передаваемые методу.

Пример изменил чуток с VB:

```
private void dataGrid1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid.HitTestInfo hti;
    hti = dataGrid1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    switch (hti.Type)
    {
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.None: 
            label1.Text = "You clicked the background."; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.Cell: 
            label1.Text = "You clicked cell at row " + hti.Row + ", col " + hti.Column; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.ColumnHeader:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the column header for column " + hti.Column; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.RowHeader:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the row header for row " + hti.Row; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.ColumnResize:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the column resizer for column " + hti.Column; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.RowResize:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the row resizer for row " + hti.Row; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.Caption:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the caption"; break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestType.ParentRows:
            label1.Text = "You clicked the parent row"; break;
    }
}
```

Ещё проще вариант :)

```
private void dataGrid1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int cellRow = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.RowNumber;
    int cellCol = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber;
}
```